# How to do math pow with decimals

Tags: c#, math, decimal

```
double variable1= 1.125;
double variable2= 1/7;

Math.Pow(variable1,variable2);
```

the problem is when using doubles variable2 returns 0 so the Math.Pow result is not acurate, i should use decimals but it is not suported with Math.Pow , what should i do ?

Comment: double variable2= 1.0/7.0;

Comment: that way it doesnt return 0?

Comment: `1` and `7` are implicitly `int`s. Integer division truncates, resulting a loss of precision. Use `1.0` and `7.0` instead (or cast each number to a double/decimal).

Comment: might I suggest: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging it will help you to see what the variables actually are in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Whe you use `1/7` C# make division in integer numbers `1/7 = 0`, so use:

```
double variable2 = 1.0/7.0;
```

Comment: its enough to specify either operand as double e.g. 1/7.0 or 1.0/7